# Problem displaying Right-to-left arabic text while viewing page in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, arabic, right-to-left

I have a sturuts application that displays some data from the database . This data consists of arabic characters. when i view the application in IE6, the right to left orientation of the arabic text is apperaing properly. But when i view the same page in IE7, the arabic text appers as left-to-right text.

Can somebody help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the text direction with the "dir" attribute.

```
<div dir=ltr> This is LeftToRight </div>

<div dir=rtl> This is RightToLeft </div>
```